# What is the meaning of 00406434 dword_406434 dd 0?

Tags: assembly

I have the following line in IDA PRO:

```
    CODE:    00406434 dword_406434   dd  0
```

I know that dword_406434 is a place where a value is stored. So, my question is:

First : What is that "dd" in that line ? 
Second: And is the 0 the value stored at dword_406434 ?

best regards,

Answer (score 6):

> First : What is that "dd" in that line ?

`dd` is short for `data, doubleword`, where "doubleword" is a 32-bit value.

> Second: And is the 0 the value stored at dword_406434 ?

Yes, the 32-bit value 0 (0x00000000) is stored in memory there.

Comment: thx for your answer